# Moodle core_role_assign_roles

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I wan't to give the user with the id 1111 in the coursecat 2222 the role courscreater ... and i use the webservice core_role_assign_roles

How can i do this .... ?

I use

https://MYMOODLE/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=MYTOKEN&wsfunction=core_role_assign_roles&moodlewsrestformat=json&assignments[0][roleid]=2&assignments[0][userid]=1111&assignments[0][contextlevel]=coursecat&assignments[0][instanceid]=2222

but it do not works ... everytime -> invlid parameter <-

thx 4 help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try switching the debug level to DEVELOPER in Moodle, this will give your more details

Site administration > Development > Debugging >

debug = developer

debugdisplay = on

Or in the `config.php` file

```
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```